# we have 2 tables: "hall" & "trainer"; we want to set "id" column from "hall" table as a foreign key in "trainer" table

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image]

```
use OOP_project
create table hall
(
 hall_name nvarchar,
 )
 ALTER TABLE trainer
ADD FOREIGN KEY (hallid) REFERENCES hall(id);

alter table hall 
add id int

create table trainer
(
  hall_name nvarchar,
  trainer_name nvarchar,
  trainer_id int
)

EXEC sp_rename 'trainer.hall_name' ,'hall_id' , 'COLUMN'
EXEC sp_rename 'trainer.hall_id' ,'hallid' , 'COLUMN'
ALTER TABLE trainer ALTER COLUMN hall_id int

 create table ex_plan
(
 trainer_name nvarchar,
 ex_name nvarchar 
)
create table equ
(
 ex_plan_name nvarchar,
 eq_name nvarchar,
 eq_id int,
 eq_type nvarchar
)
create table customer 
(
 halle_name nvarchar,
 customer_name nvarchar,
 id int,
 height float,
 [weight] float,
 new_old nvarchar,
 [date] nvarchar,
 fees int,
 edge int,
 phone int,
 gender nvarchar,
 [time] int ,

)

create table hall (id int , [name] nvarchar)
```

Comment: This looks very suspiciously like homework.

Comment: no it's not we are making mini project to get familiar with sql server

Answer (score 0):

You're doing everything backwards. You can't create the foreign key from `hall` to `trainer` if the `trainer` table doesn't even exist yet. Second, creating the foreign key requires both of the columns to exist first; trainer doesn't have a `hallid` field, even after you rename `hall_name` to `hall_id`.

SQL, like most computer languages, is fairly particular about things like order of operations and exact naming of identifiers. It's only case-sensitive if the database is set to be case-sensitive, unlike many other languages which always differentiate "A" from "a", but it can't figure out that "hall_id" is supposed to be the same thing as "hallid".

Comment: I know what you mean, but we do not run the whole program at once. we just highlight the lines we want to execute , so these lines were not executed in this order we just write anywhere